# How can i send email from/to any emails addresses like yahoo gmail pop3?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

What i tried now is to send email to my own gmail account but what ever i tried so far i'm getting error when trying to send.

I didn't try to send yet to my pop3 email and not to yahoo or from my pop3 or from yahoo. For now i'm trying to send to my gmail.

In a button click event:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    sendit("myg@gmail.com");
}
```

Then in the method sendit

```
public string sendit(string ReciverMail)
{
        MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();

        msg.From = new MailAddress("myg@gmail.com");
        msg.To.Add(ReciverMail);
        msg.Subject = "Hello world! " + DateTime.Now.ToString();
        msg.Body = "hi to you ... :)";
        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
        client.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
        client.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
        client.Port = 587;
        client.EnableSsl = true;
        client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
        client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("myg@gmail.com", "myp");
        client.EnableSsl = true;
        client.Timeout = 20000;
        try
        {
            client.Send(msg);
            return "Mail has been successfully sent!";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return "Fail Has error" + ex.Message;
        }
        finally
        {
            msg.Dispose();
        }
}
```

Using break point it's always getting to the catch part show the message:

> "The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not
>   authenticated. The server response was: 5.5.1 Authentication Required.
>   Learn more at"

Comment: Check my answer and tell me if helped you.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `client.UseDefaultCredentials = true;` and try again!

If `UseDefaultCredentials` is set, the client tries to send the E-Mail with the currently logged on user. If `UseDefaultCredentials` is false, then it is going to use your manually set Credentials!

Answer (score 0):

It is a security issue, Gmail by default prevents access for your mail account from custom applications. You need to turn on the access for less secure applications.

Here is the link: [Less secure applications](https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps)